# Model-View-ViewModel performance issue

Tags: wpf, performance, mvvm

Last time I started to implement a **Model View ViewModel** to work easily with WPF.
I have to say, that it's elegant, but there's one thing I have to remark.
I noticed a **performance issue** when working with MVVM.

Wrapping the original object into an "**Viewable**" object can be expensive in case of many items.
I recently had a ListView with about 20 000 items. It took several seconds to create the View.
Am I doint anything wrong or it's quite logical. If so, how to solve this problem ?

My example code:

```
public class AdresseVm : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {        
        public AdresseVm(Adresse adresse)
        {
            this.adresse = adresse;
        }

        private bool isChecked;
        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return isChecked; }
            set
            {
                isChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            }
        }

        private Adresse adresse;
        public Adresse Adresse
        {
            get { return adresse; }
            set
            {
                adresse = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Adresse");
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

and a main object:

```
public class AdressenVm
    {
        private IEnumerable<Adresse> adressen;
        private ObservableCollection<AdresseVm> adressenListVm = new ObservableCollection<AdresseVm>();

        public AdressenVm(IEnumerable<Adresse> adressen)
        {
            this.adressen = adressen;

            foreach (Adresse adresse in adressen)
                adressenListVm.Add(new AdresseVm(adresse));
        }

        public ObservableCollection<AdresseVm> AdressenListVm
        {
            get { return adressenListVm; }
            set { adressenListVm = value; }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Adresse> CheckedAdresses
        {
            get
            {
                foreach (AdresseVm a in adressenListVm)                
                    if (a.IsChecked) yield return a.Adresse;                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How did you end up with a ListView with 20,000 items in it?  How does a user make sense of UI contianing that many items?  Sounds like a design problem to me.

Comment: Well he has to choose on of many adresses :D.. when he sets filter.. it isn't that slow.. but in case of "display all" it is very slow.

Comment: Certainly these problems are not unique to MVVM.  20,000 items in a listview, whether populated by codebehind or a ViewModel class via binding is going to be slow to render.  Some of the Bea Stollnitz suggestions below will help.  Also, make sure and look into Virtualizing... this helps a great deal when dealing with large data sets and scrolling.

Comment: Yes I use "VirtualizingStackPanel".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dan Crevier in [part 6 of his series about MVVM](http://blogs.msdn.com/dancre/archive/2006/08/25/724938.aspx) (one of the first appearances of MVVM, he calls it DM-V-VM...) touch this topic:

> If you have a large set of items, you
>   only want to keep the visible items
>   live. We'll do this by giving models
>   Activate and Deactivate functions that
>   control when it is live. (...)
>
> Let's say we've got thousands of our models in a ListBox. It's only
>   going to only show a few of them on
>   the screen at a time and we only want
>   the ones on screen to be active. We'll
>   use the attached property trick to do
>   this without having to write custom
>   code each time we want to activate and
>   deactivate models...

More recently Bea Stollnitz also give a solutions to this problem [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150722011154/http://www.zagstudio.com:80/blog/498#.WSRjHW4lG70).
I hope this can useful to you.